# Magento 2 create links that routes to edit page

Tags: magento2, php

I am creating a module in Magento 2 where I have created a model and now I'm implmenting a simple CRUD functionality.

I have shown a list of items

```
Item name   edit
1. item1    link to edit form
2. item2    link to edit form
3. item3    link to edit form
```

I want to place this `<a href="{{ link to edit form with id}}" />`, but I don't know how to give route names in Magento 2 . Can anyone help?

Below is my code:

Controller File

```
<?php

namespace Smartshore\Subscription\Controller\Index;

use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Index extends Action
{   
    /** @var  \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
                                \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory)
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Subscription Index, shows a list of subscriptions
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

Block File

```
<?php

namespace Smartshore\Subscription\Block;

use Smartshore\Subscription\Model\Api\Data\SubscriptionInterface;
use Smartshore\Subscription\Model\ResourceModel\Subscription\Collection as SubscriptionCollection;

class SubscriptionList extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template implements
    \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Smartshore\Subscription\Model\ResourceModel\Subscription\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_subscriptionCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Smartshore\Subscription\Model\ResourceModel\Subscription\CollectionFactory $subscriptionCollectionFactory,
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Smartshore\Subscription\Model\ResourceModel\Subscription\CollectionFactory $subscriptionCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_subscriptionCollectionFactory = $subscriptionCollectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Ashsmith\Blog\Model\ResourceModel\Post\Collection
     */
    public function getSubscriptions()
    {
        // Check if subscriptions has already been defined
        // makes our block nice and re-usable! We could
        // pass the 'subscriptions' data to this block, with a collection
        // that has been filtered differently!
        if (!$this->hasData('subscriptions')) {

            $subscriptions = $this->_subscriptionCollectionFactory
                ->create()
                ->addOrder(
                    SubscriptionInterface::CREATION_TIME,
                    SubscriptionCollection::SORT_ORDER_DESC
                );

            $this->setData('subscriptions', $subscriptions);
        }

        return $this->getData('subscriptions');
    }

    /**
     * Return identifiers for produced content
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getIdentities()
    {
        return [\Smartshore\Subscription\Model\Subscription::CACHE_TAG . '_' . 'list'];
    }

}
```

This is the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Subscriptions</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Smartshore\Subscription\Block\SubscriptionList" name="subscription.list" template="Smartshore_Subscription::list.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

This is the template

```
<?php /** @var $block \Smartshore\Subscription\Block\SubscriptionList */ ?>

<h1><?php echo __('Latest Subscriptions') ?></h1>

<ul class="subscription-list">

<?php foreach ($block->getSubscriptions() as $singleSubscription): ?>
    <li class="subscription-list-item">

        <div class="subscription-item-content">
            <?php echo $singleSubscription->getPlan(); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="blog-post-item-meta">
            <strong><?php echo __('Created at:') ?></strong> <?php echo $singleSubscription->getCreationTime() ?>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>

</ul>
```

Controller Form.php

```
<?php

namespace Smartshore\Subscription\Controller\Index;


use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Form extends Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $pageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the code your have for your items grid?

Comment: I've added files in the question @Marius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a method in the class `\Smartshore\Subscription\Block\SubscriptionList` that looks like this:

```
public function getSubscriptionEditUrl($subscription)
{
    return $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl('[module_url_key_here]/index/form', [id => $subscription->getId()])
}
```

then just add in your template the url like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $block->getSubscriptionEditUrl($singleSubscription)?>"><?php echo __('Edit')?></a>
```

But I want to say that you are doing it wrong. For CRUD modules you should use ui-components to generate the grid. Check how the core modules are done. For example the cms pages section.

Comment: Can you please refer a link where I can see how to use ui-components. I am a newbie in Magento

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ui-components/ui-component.html

Comment: Can we create urls' like this /subscription/**id**/edit in Magento 2?

Comment: theoretically yes, but it's too much of a hassle to do so. The standard urls look like `{module}/{controller}/{action}/{param1_name}/{param1_value}.`

Comment: Thanks, Please see my question, I've added a file Form.php in Controller, I want to use same form for add/edit but in case of edit if I have "id" in url, I want the form fields to be filled. can you give me any idea related to that?